# Using a third party library in a node application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

In my `server.js` I have the following functions:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

I have to use [this](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid) library as well but I cannot figure out how to use this?

The documentation say that I can just do `npm install node-uuid` and `var uuid = require('node-uuid');`

I tried to add `var uuid = require('node-uuid');` to `server.js` but I cannot use `uuid` in any controller js file like `var id = uuid.v1();`. I get `Error: Can't find variable: uuid`.

The controller file looks like this:

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module("WebApp")
        .controller("TestController", TestController);

    function TestController($location) {
        // need to get a uuid here
    }

})();
```

How should I use this library?

Comment: The code in your post is server side code, whereas Angular is a client side framework. How are you including your angular code? With `<script` tags in an html / template file?

Comment: Definitely seem to be confusing server side includes and client side

Comment: @azium I have updated the question. I was trying to use the library as given in the documentation on github using `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

If your code above  client-side code and you really trying to achieve that on client side with angular framework you can try AngularJS wrapper for the original node-uuid library i.e angular-uuid.

Create angular-uuid.js file in your js folder of client
use this link to copy the contents for this file
https://github.com/munkychop/angular-uuid/blob/master/angular-uuid.js
and save this file with the copied contents.

use a regular script tag to include this lib

```
<script src="angular-uuid.js"></script>
```

Include angular-uuid in your module defination and inject that in your controller

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module("WebApp",["angular-uuid"])
        .controller("TestController", ["uuid",TestController]);

    function TestController(uuid) {
        // need to get a uuid here
    }

})();
```

Comment: The `angular-uuid.js` is in `node_modules` directory. Do I need to move it to  current folder otherwise `<script src="angular-uuid.js"></script>` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

npm install won't do you any good in your client-side angular code since it has no access to the node_modules.

In the page you linked above, the instructions say to include it in your html with something like:

```
<script src="uuid.js"></script>
```

If you do that, then if your controller code runs after the script noted above has been loaded, then you should be good to go.

If your code above isn't client-side code, then I'm not sure what you're doing with angular on the server side.

NOTE: If you're using bundling with something like web-pack then you could use npm to install the uuid library. Please let us know if you're doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use node modules in the frontend if you use a bundler like [webpack](http://webpack.github.io) or [browserify](http://browserify.org). In that case you can do:

```
var uuid = require('uuid');
```

Just like you can on the backend. Make sure you link the files bundled by the bundler you chose, and this should work.

Keep in mind that there's a (slight) performance difference between loading it in a script tag (more http requests) vs using a bundler (larger file size).